# Setup Apache HTTPS in Amazon WS with ACM

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-web-services

I have an Amazon Ubuntu 16 instance running Apache but now I want to have it under HTTPS. I got a certificate for my site using ACM. I been trying to find ways to set it up but I am still a bit lost. I been trying to follow http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html but I get stuck in with the files .key and .crt which I can't figure out how to get them.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean using ACM? If you do have a valid cert you should have those files. One would be the certificate and the other would be the private key.

Comment: ACM = AWS Certificate Manager. I did not get any files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use ACM certificates with your Apache. Those certificates are managed by AWS and are not available for download. Here is an excerpt from the FAQ https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/:

> Q: Can I use certificates on Amazon EC2 instances or on my own
>   servers?
>
> No. At this time, certificates provided by ACM can only be used with
>   specific AWS services.
>
> Q: With which AWS services can I use certificates provided by ACM?
>
> You can use ACM with the following AWS services:
>
> Elastic Load Balancing
>
> Amazon CloudFront
>
> Amazon API Gateway

Comment: It's been updated to state: "You can use private certificates issued with ACM Private CA with EC2 instances, containers, and on your own servers." But public certs are still limited.

Comment: Answer can be improved with an alternative to using ACM certificates.